# Problem with middleware in NextJS12.3 in production mode

Tags: node.js, next.js

currently I'm working on a nextJS project that uses version 12.3.0.
recently I'm going to use some features under the file called middleware.js.
at first, nothing is in it:

```
export function middleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Middleware called");
  }
```

In my local machine, it works perfectly fine but in production mode, when I deployed it on the server, the entire application got application error.

if there are some roles when using middleware in production mode I would be thankful to let me know about them.